# Corollary from Theorem on Acyclic Carriers in Hilton and Wylie's Homology Theory

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $C=(C_p, \partial_p)$ and $D=(D_p, \partial_p)$ two free chain complexes in category
of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, ie every $C_q, D_p$ is freely generated.

A *carrier (function)* $E$ of a chain map $\phi$ from a geometric
chain complex $C$ (geometric means $C_p=0$ for $p <-1$) to the chain complex $D$ is a function defined on the
basis elements $\gamma^i_p$ of $C$ whose values are subcomplexes of $D$ such that,
if $\gamma_{p-1} $ apears with nonzero coefficient in the direct sum decomposition of $\partial \gamma_{p}$ which respect to this free basis, then $E(\gamma_{p-1}) \subset E(\gamma_{p})$. $E$ is said to be acyclic if each
$E(\gamma)$ is acyclic, i.e. $H_*(E(\gamma))=0$ for every basis element $\gamma$ of $C$. (see the book for details on the terminology)

In the book *Homology Theory: An Introduction to Algebraic Topology* by P. J. Hilton, S. Wylie the Theorem on Acyclic Carriers (p 109) states:

**3.4.3 Theorem:** If the chain map $\phi: C \to D$ from the geometric chain complex
$C$ to the chain complex $D$ is carried by an acyclic carrier $E$, then $\phi \simeq 0$, i.e. $\phi$ is homotopic to zero map.

The subsequent Corollary 3.4.4 is not clear to me:

**3.4.4 Corollary.** If the chain maps $\phi, \psi: C \to D$ are both carried by
a acyclic carrier $E$, then these are homotopic $\phi \simeq \psi $.

First of all, I think that $C $ should be presumably assumed to be a geometric complex like in the theorem before (If not, I don't see why this corollary should follow from the previous Theorem, because the theorem requires existence of zero 'bottom
dimension' for making an inductive argument in the proof).
But the main point which confuses me is that the rather strong assumtion that $\phi, \psi: C \to D$ are *both!!* carried by
a acyclic carrier $E$, since it would immediately imply that we can even apply the previous theorem 3.4.3 to each $\phi $ and $ \psi$ separately and will obtain the overkill statement that $\phi \simeq 0 \simeq \psi $, but I guess that is not what we want. It sounds more reasonable that the objection is to show that $\phi $ and $ \psi$ are homotopic to each other and not that they are both zero homotopic, or not?

Therefore I conjecture that presumably we want to apply 3.4.4 to the *difference* $\phi -  \psi $ and conclude something like $\phi -  \psi \simeq 0 $. Shouldn't it in that case not be more reasonable to assume that the difference $\phi -  \psi $ is carried by $E$, and **not** that each $\phi, \psi $ carried by $E$ separately, since otherwise we would obtain as explained before the rather overkill statement that $\phi \simeq 0 \simeq \psi $? And therefore at this point I doubt that this is what the authors intended for Corollary 3.4.4.

Therefore I not understand the importance of Corollary 3.4.4 as tool to compare two chain maps $\phi, \psi$ if anyway under given assumtions the two maps are zero homotopic due to Theorem 3.4.3. Or do I missing an important point in Corollary 3.4.4? Could somebody help to resolve my confusion on this corollary?